# Avatar src or children on ListItem

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to make a wrapper for avatar to render the first letter of the name as the children when src is not provided. The problem is that when I put to ListItem's leftAvatar prop, it doesnt render in the same line.

```
import React from 'react';
import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar';

export default function UserAvatar(props) {
    const {
        size,
        src,
        name
    } = props;

    return (
        <Avatar
            size={size || 40}
            src={src || null}
        >
            {src ? null : name.charAt(0)}
        </Avatar>
    );
}

UserAvatar.propTypes = {
    name: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    size: React.PropTypes.number,
    src: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

When I want to render it :

```
            import UserAvatar from './UserAvatar';
            ...
            <ListItem
                primaryText={post.title}
                secondaryText={post.user.firstName}
                   leftAvatar={<UserAvatar
                    src={post.user.avatar}
                    name={post.user.firstName}
                            />
                   }
                leftAvatar={post.user.avatar}
            />
```

Here's the render

[image: Render]

Expected render (when I dont use my wrapper)

[image: Expected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited my answer, found true cause, is not a bug in material-ui)...

You need to pass the "style" property onto the `<Avatar />`.  The `ListItem` is cloning your leftAvatar element and adding a style onto it that includes position: absolute, left, top, etc. By not spreading the props (i.e. using `{...props}`), or copying the `style` property, you're unintentionally omitting it.

```
export default function UserAvatar(props) {
    const {
        size,
        src,
        name,
        style // <- Need to pull from props, ListItem put it here with React.cloneElement
    } = props;

    return (
        <Avatar
            style={style}  // <- Pass it onto the actual material-ui Avatar
            size={size || 40}
            src={src || null}
        >
            {src ? null : name.charAt(0)}
        </Avatar>
    );
}
```